# Software for creating Win-Applications

Tags: windows, c#, gui, sql, gui-builder

I have been looking for a software solution for writing Windows applications with GUI in which I can access MS-ACCESS and SQL databases. I would prefer C#.

However, I'm just looking for free variants that still allow me to use the applications in the company. 
I have now tried Python with pygubu and that's all else, at least for me, as a fast development. 
The next are the licenses with which I am not well versed and which I can not interpret correctly.
I have tried SharpDevelop privately and am actually very satisfied. And there are the problems with the licenses. 
Is the C # compiler from Microsoft "license free" or do I have to buy Visual Studio?
I hope someone can bring some light into the darkness?

Answer (score 1):

You can just use [Visual Studio Community](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/).

[image: Visual Studio 2013 screenshot]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I think the company I work for is too big for the community edition so have to buy one of the bigger versions... If there are no free alternatives, then I have to buy a version. But I would like to inform myself about different possibilities to save costs as far as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I heard good things about [Gambas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambas) . See also the ["See Also" links](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambas#See_also) at the bottom of that Wikipedia article - they lead to very long lists of IDEs and VB Dialects.

Answer (score 0):

Consider trying [MonoDevelop](https://www.monodevelop.com/), which is the base used for Visual Studio for macOS. Note that you would have to build it from source for Windows.